# What are symptoms of resource(thread) depletion of Node.js application running on V8 engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Node.js is single threaded and uses other thread (worked threads) spawn by underlying V8 for async processing of e.g. IO. As amount of these spawned threads is finite, we could land in situation where single Node.js server would start lagging.

e.g. Let's say we have Node application with endpoint which does complex select on DB table and we will spawn 10K requests simultaneously. I imagine all request can potentially be offloaded to these aforementioned threads spawned by V8 instance and can cause some issues.

**What are observable symptoms of such resource depletion?**

I can imagine that this would be for single request:

1. request comes to Node.js app
2. request is handled in event loop
3. when request handler does DB call, it's "paused" till we will get response from secondary thread/or maybe DB directly/ about finish (this will schedule code to be executed after it will land in queue for main thread)
4. DB response will be used in code
5. web request response is sent back to the client

Comment: Average response time increases, at some point requests time out. Hard to say, it depends how you use the NodeJS instance.

Comment: DB requests do not spawn threads. What makes you think they do?

Comment: @Bergi where can I find how they work then? I imagine all offloaded tasks may go into worker thread pool. I know there are some basic things that can be delegated to OS level, but how they post results back to be picked up to Event loop. DB call is IO and IO operations are supposed to be not stopping event loop and just be delegated.

Comment: @zmii https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/ https://medium.com/softup-technologies/node-js-internals-not-everything-happens-on-the-thread-pool-a14d0a286efb DB requests are basic things that can be delegated to async OS APIs.

Comment: @zmii AFAIK threads are used only for disk IO. Maybe for something else as well, but network IO is definitely implemented over async apis, which are not thread based. The mechanism heavily depends on the underlying OS, but for posix this is typically done via epoll or kqueue. Of course you can run out of these resources as well, but the limit is much, much higher (of the order of tens of thousands) than with simple threads.